# How do you glue two topologies $\{U\}, \ \{V\}$ together so that $U \cap V$ is always in the new topology?

Tags: general-topology

Say you have a space $X$, and two topologies defined on $X$, one generated by the basis $\{U_a\}$ and the other by the basis $\{V_a\}$ then can we easily define a new topology such that $U_a \cap V_b$ is always open?

Also, the new topology should contain the old ones.

Comment: @RolfHoyer added a note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology generated by the basis $\{U_a \cap V_b\}$ will suffice.  To check that this yields a basis, assume that $x$ lies in the intersection of $U_a\cap V_b$ and $U_c \cap V_d$  Then there exist $e,f$ such that $x \in U_e \subset U_a \cap U_c$ and $x\in V_f \subset V_b \cap V_d$.  Then $x\in U_e \cap V_f \subset (U_a \cap V_b) \cap (U_c \cap V_d)$, as desired.

To see that the resulting topology refines the two starting topologies, we will check that $U$ open in the topology generated by the $\{U_a\}$ implies that $U$ is open in the topology generated by the $\{U_a \cap V_b\}$.  For any $x\in U$, choose $a$ such that $x\in U_a \subset U$ and choose an arbitrary $b$ such that $x\in V_b$.  Then $x\in U_a \cap V_b \subset U_a \subset U$, so that $U$ is open in the new topology, as desired.

Comment: You can also note that the other condition for being a base, that $\cup \{U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\beta}\}=X$, is satisfied, because every $x\in X$ belongs to some $U\in \{U_{\alpha}\}$  and to some $V\in \{V_{\beta}\}$  so $x\in U\cap V\in \{U_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}\}$.